# Debugging a broken Wordpress install where the file name and path causing the error doesn't seem to even exist

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I've been tasked to complete what appears to be a migration of a Wordpress site from a development URL (`/newblog`) to a production URL (root) that seemed to have already been attempted by somebody else and got messy somewhere along the way and am seeing errors I have never seen before.

After seeing some really strange things (I tracked down an error earlier that involved me simply resaving a file with the same contents - it was as if some kind of cache was in operation), I got an error like what I pasted below (obviously `examplesite.com` is a made up domain).

What I don't understand is that there is no such directory called /newblog anymore, so how can it be saying the error is found in `/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/widget.php` ?

I've checked the database and there is no reference to any path with `/newblog` in it.

> Warning:
> include_once(/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/widget.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php
> on line 49
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
> '/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/widget.php'
> for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
> /var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php
> on line 49
>
> Warning:
> require_once(/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack-user-agent.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php
> on line 4467
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack-user-agent.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
> /var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php
> on line 4467

Answer (score 1):

Using your example path:

```
/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/widget.php
```

This fragment of that path:

```
/var/www/examplesite.com/newblog/
```

Is basically the base install path that is usually stored in `wp_options` in `siteurl`, `home`, `dashboard_widget_options` and even others. But when it comes to migrating an install—like what you are attempting to do—it can really get in the way.

The issue is that WordPress attempts to make initial installs so simple, they make them hard to migrate. The best solution that I use on a regular basis is to hard-code the install paths within the `wp-config.php` file like this:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.examplesite.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.examplesite.com');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/www.examplesite.com/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.examplesite.com/wp-content');
```

Of course, the settings I have set above are based on my best guess of your setup. Assuming a standard Unix `/var/www/` install path and your site URL.  But in general—and in my experience—simply setting these paths explicitly in your `wp-config.php` is the best way to go to migrate a site & even make it more portable.

Also, check the `.haccess` file. It should basically be:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But if someone placed the site in a directory on the server that is not the root—like `newblog`—it could be something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newblog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newblog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Note the two places where `newblog` are in that example above. But from what you describe it all sounds like a config issue.

And if worse comes to worse, I recommend you figure out what version of WordPress the site is using—look in the file `/wordpress/wp-includes/version.php`—and then download a clean install of WordPress, set the config to load the old/damaged site’s database & such & then copy the `wp-content` folder from the old install into the new install. Hopefully the previous developer did not muck with the WordPress core files, so just copying the `wp-content` & using the old directory should help you out.

Comment: I'm just curious though where would '/newblog' actually be floating around though? Is it encrypted or something? When I do a mysql dump and do a search I find nothing when I search '/newblog'. Thanks!

Comment: I've checked .htaccess it looks like your first example. I've also changed your settings in wp-config and I am seeingthe same issue. Must have done this 50+ times before and never seen anything like it!